# LXD vs classic VMs in production Cluster (Kubernetes)

Tags: kubernetes, virtual-machine, vmware, lxc, lxd

I'm setting up a bare-metal hypervisor with VMware ESXi on a local server which will have a kubernetes cluster.

Should I use Linux containers with **LXD** to set up my Kubernetes cluster? or should I use several **VMs** that I can provide with my VMware hypervisor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are referring to by using LXD to set up your Kubernetes cluster. Kubernetes doesn't officially support [LXC/LXD](https://linuxcontainers.org/).

So, you can use several VMs for your Kubernetes control (masters) and data planes (nodes). You can either use [straight](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/pkg/kubelet/dockershim) docker or any [containerd](https://containerd.io/) or [cri-o](https://cri-o.io/) as shims to run your container runtime.

In any case, most of this stuff is already set up by the deployment tools like:

- [kubespray](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubespray)
- [kubeadm](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/)
- [kops](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops)
- Vendor offerings (EKS, GKS, AKS, etc)
- etc

If you are looking for something more minimal you can try:

- [minikube](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-minikube/)
- [kind](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/)
- [microk8s](https://microk8s.io/)
- [K3s](https://k3s.io/)

Comment: I ve seeing some post`s telling that they have set up their kubernetes nodes inside several linux containers and that they have being working correctly .
But im not pretty sure to set up mine with kubeadm as you suggest me inside of them , I also keep asking me why not to setup this cluster inside linux containers, if they are more manageable with more pros than a vm and faster to boot up

Comment: I guess you can try setting it up in an LXC container using `kubeadm`

Comment: added more options